# lsof command on HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs

I would like to know if a file is currently being used or opened on HDFS.

I am trying to use the below command, but it's not working. Can someone give me the correct command to do this?

```
hadoop fs -lsof  /apps/hive/warehouse/db/table/.hive-staging_*
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such command (see [list of available commands](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html)), but you can check for inconsistencies in HDFS using [`hdfs fsck`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html#fsck) together with the option `-openforwrite` to list files that are stuck in the `OPENFORWRITE` status

```
hdfs fsck <your_hdfs_path> -files -blocks -locations -openforwrite
```